# DICCIONARIOS, ASIGNACIÓN DE LETRAS A CALIFICACIONES

Tags: python, python-2.7

estoy con el último ejercicio de diccionarios de las calificaciones de unos alumnos, una vez hecha la ficha, la media y la calificación final ponderada, hay que hacer una asignación de letra, según la calificación obtenida, evidentemente con un for es suficiente pero sólo asigna una letra a una calificación, el resto no las toca y no entiendo el motivo. Tengo hecho esto:

```
diccionario_final={'lloyd':67.0,'alice':75.8,'tyler':61.43}
def obtener_letra():
    for i in diccionario_final.values():
        if i>=90:
            return 'A'
        elif 80<=i<90:
            return 'B'
        elif 70<=i<80:
            return 'C'
        elif 60<=i<70:
            return 'D'
        else:
            return 'F'
print obtener_letra()
```

El resultado es:
D
No entiendo que no asigne las otras dos notas, si me echan una mano se lo agradecería

Comment: Una vez que haces el `return` la función ya no se ejecutará más. Por eso se sale en la primera iteración. ¿Qué se supone que debería devolverte la función? ¿Una lista con las letras A,B, etc? En ese caso en lugar de retornar la letra deberías ir guardándola en una lista interna de la función para, una vez terminado el bucle, retornar esa lista.

Comment: Mejor aún, la función `obtener_letra()` debería recibir un parámetro, la nota a convertir en letra, y por tanto olvidarse de bucles. Su única misión sería convertir la (única) nota que recibe como parámetro en una letra. Entonces desde el programa principal podrías hacer: `for alumno, nota in diccionario_final.items(): print alumno, obtener_letra(nota)`

Answer (score 2):

Una solución más corta:

```
diccionario_final={'lloyd':67.0,'alice':75.8,'tyler':61.43, 'albert': 100, 'tonto': 1}

def obtener_letra(calificacion):
    return "FFFFFFDCBAA"[int(calificacion / 10)]

for alumno, nota in diccionario_final.items():
    print(alumno, obtener_letra(nota))
```

Como norma de diseño, es mejor que la función procese sólo un alumno a la vez; si requieres procesar una lista, un diccionario o cualquier otro contenedor de alumnos, puedes reutilizar la misma función de calificación.

Para obtener la letra usamos la nota como indice en una lista de letras. Para reducir el tamaño de la lista, dividimos la nota por 10. Esto nos da 10 posibles calificaciones, por lo que la lista de letras se reduce a

```
"FFFFFFDCBAA"
```

donde la letra en el índice 0 corresponde a las notas entre 0 y 9.99. La letra en el índice 1 corresponde al rango 10.0 a 19.99, etc.

**Resultado**

El código anterior produce

```
lloyd D
alice C
tyler D
albert A
tonto F
```

Comment: Excelente, pero si quieres cambiar, por ejemplo, el rango para la puntuación D para que sea entre 65 y 70, ¿cómo se modificaría tu código para reflejar el cambio?

Answer (score 1):

```
diccionario_final={'lloyd':67.0,'alice':75.8,'tyler':61.43}

def obtener_letra():
    res = []
    for i in diccionario_final.values():
        if i>=90:
            res.append('A')
        elif 80<=i<90:
            res.append('B')
        elif 70<=i<80:
            res.append('C')
        elif 60<=i<70:
            res.append('D')
        else:
            res.append('F')
    return res

print(obtener_letra())
```

Tu código está muy bien pero la función solo devuelve una letra porque solo se ejecuta un `return`.

Una solución es crear una lista en la que ir añadiendo las letras de calificación, y posteriormente imprimir la lista.

El resultado es:

```
['D', 'C', 'D']
```